# How to remove only images which are removed from webpage using Javascript

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core MVC. I have created one product CREAT page which allows users to create product and upload multiple images of that product.

Now in editing page of this product I display all these pictures in `<div>` tag, with javascript of delete function to delete the picture which user want to remove and save the product details again.

From this point I don't understand how to tell ProductController.cs that which images should be deleted from database and which shouldn't.

Can someone put me on right direction, how exactly this process should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can fire jquery call at each image delete; works for smaller set of images
2. You can store the deleted image-ids in an array and serialize the array to an hidden field and pass the array when you make one jquery call to ProductController.cs on edit submit.

You can check this repository for the solution

https://github.com/rajdeepdebnath/aspnetcore-mvc-collection

My view

```
@model List<WebApplication4.Controllers.Product>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (Model != null)
    {

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Desc</th>
                    <th>Images</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    var product = Model[i];
                    var id = $"product[{i}].Id";
                    var name = $"product[{i}].Name";
                    var description = $"product[{i}].Description";

                    <tr>
                        <td>@product.Id<input type="hidden" value="@product.Id" name='@id' /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@product.Name" name='@name' /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="@product.Description" name='@description' /></td>
                        <td>
                            @foreach (var image in product.ImageIdArr)
                            {
                                <span class="image" data-imageid="@image" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px;background-color:darkseagreen;"></span>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" value="[]" name="DeleteImageIdArr" id="DeleteImageIdArr" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
}

@section Scripts{


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.image').click(function (v) {
                console.log(v);
                console.log(v.target.dataset.imageid);
                var arr = [];
                arr = JSON.parse($('#DeleteImageIdArr').val());
                console.log(Array.isArray(arr));

                if (arr.indexOf(v.target.dataset.imageid) < 0) {
                    arr.push(v.target.dataset.imageid);
                }

                $('#DeleteImageIdArr').val(JSON.stringify(arr))

                console.log($('#DeleteImageIdArr').val());
                console.log(v.target.hidden);
                v.target.hidden = true;
            });

            $.ajax();
        });
    </script>
}
```

My controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = GetProducts();
            return View(products);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(List<Product> product, string[] DeleteImageIdArr)
        {
            var products = GetProducts();

            return View("Index", products);
        }

        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            var products = new List<Product> {
                new Product{ Id=1, Name="Test 1", Description="Test 1", ImageIdArr=new int[]{ 1,2,3 } },
                new Product{ Id=1, Name="Test 2", Description="Test 2", ImageIdArr=new int[]{ 4,5,6 } },
                new Product{ Id=1, Name="Test 3", Description="Test 3", ImageIdArr=new int[]{ 7,8,9 } },
            };

            return products;
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int[] ImageIdArr { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample code. I am new to asp.net core mvc.

Comment: Yes, which approach will meet your requirement best?

Comment: I think in first approach, image file will be deleted directly from Database, whereas user might don't want to save the changes. Can you please help with second approach where images will be removed from users view and when Save page will be hit, at that time changes will take place in Db.